# the jquerymobile toolbar should not create history entry

Tags: jquery-mobile, browser-history

If you look at the page http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html you see a toolbar with selectors for Basics, Options, Methods. It loads different pages so it acts like it's a nav bar within the page.

However, each time you click one of those things, it makes an entry in your history. If you have a page like this with a data-rel=back button on it, or the user clicks the back button, it takes you to the previous toolbar selection, whereas you'd expect to get entirely off the page.

How can I have a toolbar like this that has anchor tags that don't pollute the history?

In my app this toolbar represents a preferences setting and based on the setting, additional settings below will become available. So I need to be able to tap [back] and get out of the settings page.

Comment: If you link to a `data-role="dialog"` element then you can stop jQuery Mobile from adding the navigation to the URL: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html (Look under "Link Examples").

Comment: I did try that... but dialog comes with a lot of baggage, like restyling to look like a modal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like anchor tags are not appropriate for this kind of use. Anchors are just designed to leave history behind. I've switched to radio buttons (they can be styled to appear the same) and then I can show/hide sections of the document according to which radio is selected through a callback.

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Team role:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="list" checked/>
            <label for="radio-view-a">Robot</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="grid"  />
            <label for="radio-view-b">Controller</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I think this solution is great. Can you share the styles as well, so that a radio-button group looks like, for e.g., a navbar? Thanks.